# If I have an infinite series, how do I know that the digits I calculated are rigth?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

For example, there are infinite series for $\pi$, $e$, $\phi$... But if I sum a finite ammount of terms, I get an approximation for the series. How do I know how much correct digits of this approximation are correct? Like, suppose I got:

$$\pi \approx\color{Blue}{3,141592}\color{Red}{4265927659}$$

How do I know that the only rigth digits for $\pi$ are $\color{Blue}{3,141592}$?

Is there a book or article about it? Is there a theorem that tells me about how much I have to calculate to get $n$ digits of correctness?

Comment: The first question is 'Does the series converge?'. There are tests for this. Your question follows on from that question. I want to know the answer myself.

Comment: You need an estimate of the error of the partial sums. Without it, there really is no way to know.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but is there a general way of doing it, like, with theorems, or each series has its own difficulties?

Comment: If you got a program to calculate the partial sums and after a certain number of terms the digits to the left of a given digit remained constant you would then have to prove that this was so to answer the OP's question.

Comment: To put it another way - all subsequent terms must only add amounts that cannot change digits that have stopped changing.

Comment: No general theorem that works with all series - I'm not even sure how that would work. There might be some theorems that cover specific types of series...

Comment: Use Windows Calculator.

Comment: Yeah what about the Taylor remainder theorem for those specific power series?